# Make events visually span over multiple resources

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to make events visually span over all the resources when 1 event is held in all the resources.

Here is a simplified pen of my data https://codepen.io/mike66187/pen/VwyONwa

and this is what i want to achieve with it [resources with spanned event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXh1Q.png)

code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var date = new Date();
  date.setUTCHours(12)
  date.setUTCMinutes(0)
  
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B'},
      { id: 'c', title: 'Room C' },
      { id: 'd', title: 'Room D' }
    ],
    events: [ {
      id: '1',
      resourceIds: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: date
    }]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: There is no way to do this short of writing a custom view

Comment: Of course you can assign the same event to multiple resources, which will show up, and conveys the same kind of information, but doesn't have the specific visual effect you've indicated.

Comment: Sadly the effect is exactly the thing i am looking after for my use case :(. Ill look into making a custom view. I was hoping i had missed some fancy feature that would take the heavy lifting away :)

Comment: Of course you should bear in mind that the way it is currently designed takes account of the fact that the resources associated with the event may not always be contiguous (e.g. if the event was associated with resources a, c, and d  then your approach would not work because it could not overlap into b, which is shown between a and c). I didn't write any of the fullCalendar code but I suspect that is probably the main reason why your suggestion isn't already implemented.

Comment: Yeah i thought of that too but in that case its okay to have the event in every column. In my actual app events are either in 1 resource or in all resources.